No boot disk on HP Elitebook Folio 1020 G1
On my HP Elitebook 8740w, Ubuntu runs fine. On my HP Elitebook Folio 1020 G1, I can't get it working. The black startup screen says:
Boot Device Not Found

Please install an operating system on your hard disk.

Hard Disk - (3F0)

etc. etc.

I tried Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1, and some older LTS versions of Ubuntu.

I can install Windows 10 without any issues, but I would like Ubuntu because the HP Elitebook Folio 1020 G1 doesn't support Windows 11 and Windows 10 will end next year (and is becoming slow on my notebook).
I can launch Ubuntu on the USB stick to try and install it.
I don't see grub within the boot options when I press ESC/F9 during boot time.
I tried with BIOS in Legacy Mode and BIOS in (hybrid) UEFI mode.
I defaulted all my BIOS settings and BIOS security settings several times to factory settings, and I tried several BIOS security settings.
I re-installed almost 10 times already, both in complete disk reset mode and in the manual partition mode. When I install alongside Windows 10, it ends up in an error after I completed all the installation screens.
The boot repair utility doesn't solve the issue.

When I run Ubuntu in "Try Ubuntu" mode from the USB stick, I notice the ext4 partition (/dev/sda2) is mounted to /target. On my working HP Elitebook 8740w it's mounted to "filesystem root". Is it displaying /target instead of "filesystem root" because I run "Try Ubuntu" from the USB stick? By the way, I cannot change the mounting point because it's busy or something.
Two questions:

What should I do to get it working?
I'm more than willing to pay for a working OS after so many hours of trial-and-error, for example Zorin. But will I run into the same issue when I buy Zorin?

Thanks in advance!
SJW
